# Find the values of the polynomial equation.

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

Find the values of A, B and C such that $A(x^2+4)+(x-2)(Bx+C)=7x^2-x+14$

My attempt to solve the question:

$Ax^2+4A+Bx^2+Cx-2Bx-2C=7x^2-x+14$
$Ax^2+Bx^2+Cx-2Bx+4A-2C=7x^2-x+14$
$x^2(A+B)+x(C-2B)+2(2A-C)=7x^2-x+14$

$x^2(A+B)=7x^2  ,  A+B=7$

$x(C-2B)=-x  ,  C-2B=-1$

$2(2A-C)=14  ,  2A-C=7$

From what I have here I can't group any to solve for a letter because the letters in each equation is different. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good so far.

Hint: Take your first equation and write it as $A = 7-B$ then substitute that into the third equation (replace $A$ with $7-B$).  Then you have 2 equations with 2 variables... the second equation (unchanged) and the modified third equation.

Really, you can choose any equation and any variable, then solve that equation for that variable and substitute into the other 2 equations so that you are left with 2 equations and 2 variables.  I just chose $A$ in the first equation because it seemed easy.

Answer (score 1):

Note if you put $x=2$ in the initial equation you eliminate $B$ and $C$ straight away. You then get the value of $A$. If you set $x=0$ the term in $B$ disappears, and if you know $A$ you can find $B$.

This is a trick (choosing a special value of $x$) which is often useful - equations like this come up all the time with partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly reached this:$$A+B=7\tag{1}$$$$C-2B=-1\tag{2}$$$$2A-C=7\tag{3}$$Now if you double equation (1) and add it to equation (2) then you will eliminate $B$. Then add the resulting equation to (3) you will eliminate $C$ and can hence solve for $A$. Hope you can complete from here on...